# How to replace cpx in package.json script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am working to refactor an old code, need to replace cpx package as it has been abandoned. So I have a below line in package.json file:

```js
"scripts": {
    "dist": "cpx node_modules/**/dist/*.* Content/lib --v & cpx node_modules/**/dist/**/*.* Content/lib",
    "media": "cpx node_modules/**/media/*.* Content/lib --v & cpx node_modules/**/media/**/*.* Content/lib",
    "build": "npm run dist && npm run media"
  }
```

I don't know node, npm much. Tried to replace cpx with cpx2, but when building fs-extra and universalify give errors "TypeError name is not defined". What is the purpose of above line and how it could be refactored? Appreciate the help.

Errors are below:

```
    node_modules\universalify\index.js:15
2021-10-13T14:40:10.4697291Z   }, 'name', { value: fn.name })
2021-10-13T14:40:10.4697705Z                          ^
2021-10-13T14:40:10.4698282Z TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined                                                                                                                                         \node_modules\universalify\index.js:15
2021-10-13T14:40:10.4689312Z   }, 'name', { value: fn.name })
2021-10-13T14:40:10.4689805Z                          ^
2021-10-13T14:40:10.4690389Z TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure using `cpx2` is related to this error?

Comment: Can you show the whole error with stacktrace?